# STDDEV function in hive query

Tags: sql, hive

I am having issues using `STDDEV` function in my below query. The inner sub query is working fine but when I run the entire query I am getting an error:

> expression not in `GROUP BY` key `NO_OF_LBR_ONLY_CLAIMS`

Please help.

```
SELECT C.NO_OF_LBR_ONLY_CLAIMS,
       C.TOTAL_CLAIMS_FOR_DEALER,
       C.BAC,
       C.COUNTRY_CD,
       C.PCT_OF_LBR_ONLY_CLAIMS,
       C.AVG_PCT_LOC_FOR_ALL_DEALERS,
       STDDEV(C.PCT_OF_LBR_ONLY_CLAIMS) AS STD_DEV,
       (C.PCT_OF_LBR_ONLY_CLAIMS - C.AVG_PCT_LOC_FOR_ALL_DEALERS)/STDDEV(C.PCT_OF_LBR_ONLY_CLAIMS) AS RI_1
FROM
  (SELECT A.NO_OF_LBR_ONLY_CLAIMS,
          A.TOTAL_CLAIMS_FOR_DEALER,
          A.BAC,
          A.COUNTRY_CD,
          A.PCT_OF_LBR_ONLY_CLAIMS,
          B.AVG_PCT_LOC_FOR_ALL_DEALERS
   FROM DBO.RISK_IND_01_TMP1 AS A
   LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT SUM(PCT_OF_LBR_ONLY_CLAIMS)/COUNT(DISTINCT BAC) AS AVG_PCT_LOC_FOR_ALL_DEALERS,
             COUNTRY_CD
      FROM DBO.RISK_IND_01_TMP1
      GROUP BY COUNTRY_CD) AS B ON A.COUNTRY_CD = B.COUNTRY_CD) C
```

Comment: `stddev()` is an aggregation function so it should be used in an aggregation query.

Comment: is there a way to calculate the STDDEV separately and join to the result set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want standard deviation over the entire set to be replicated on each row, then use window functions:

```
   STDDEV(C.PCT_OF_LBR_ONLY_CLAIMS) OVER () AS STD_DEV,
```

Answer (score 0):

You should but alias b after the second table name then join and lastly group by

COUNTRY_CD
FROM DBO.RISK_IND_01_TMP1 as b

That should hopefully work